# Перебирать от наибольшей общей последовательности к меньшей?

Tags: алгоритм, псевдокод

Есть две последовательности из символов, например

```
abcdebcdeeedde
aaadeeed
```

Я пытаюсь найти наибольшую общую подпоследовательность, удовлетворяющую некоему условию (*абстрактный пример*, в наибольшей общей подпоследовательности должно содержаться три символа `e`), при этом есть функция для проверки подпоследовательности на это условие.

Так как длина строк не очень большая (до тысячи), думаю, есть смысл проверять в цикле на это условие все *Общие Последовательности*, начиная от *Наибольшей* до тех пор, пока не переберутся все *Общие последовательности*.

Есть масса алгоритмов поиска *Наибольшей Общей Подпоследовательности* (`LCS`), но никто не ставил задачи спуститься в менее большие подпоследовательности, при необходимости дойдя до наименьшей общей подпоследовательности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возьмите алгоритм поиска методом динамического программирования. В процессе построения матрицы фиксируйте в дополнительной таблице соотношение (значение-подпоследовательность[-координаты]) для подпоследовательностей, соответствующих критерию. По завершении возьмите из дополнительной таблицы запись с максимальным значением.